# Modify a column in a table

Tags: sql

I have the following table test

```
iD Name    ParentId   GroupID  DisplayingOrder
 ---------------------------------------------
    1            1        1      Null
    2            1        1      Null
    3            1        1      Null
    4            7        2      Null
    5            7        2      Null
    6            7        2      Null
    7            9        3      Null
```

How can I modify it to get

```
iD Name    ParentId   GroupID  DisplayingOrder
 ---------------------------------------------
    1            1        1      1
    2            1        1      2
    3            1        1      3
    4            7        2      1
    5            7        2      2
    6            7        2      3
    7            9        3      1
```

Logic : increment DisplayingOrder for the same GroupID

Comment: You just asked the same question. Edit your exsiting questions if they need improvement.

Comment: @juergend . . . This isn't an exact duplicate.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, it very much is a duplicate - a solution to the linked question should contain a solution to this (very very similar) problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the both UPDATES in one query you dont need to break it down in two statements. see below :

```
; WITH CTE 
AS
 (
 SELECT iDName, ParentId, GroupID,DisplayingOrder 
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ParentId ASC) RN1
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentId ORDER BY ParentId) RN2
  FROM TEST
 )
UPDATE CTE 
SET  GroupID         = RN1
    ,DisplayingOrder = RN2
```

### [`Sql Fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0403c/1)

Also if you can have a look at [`SQL SERVER RANKING FUNCTIONS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx), it will really help you :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an exact duplicate of the earlier question.  But a very similar approach can work:

```
WITH toupdate AS
      (SELECT iDName, ParentId, GroupID,
              row_number() over (partition by groupid order by idName) as newDisplayingOrder
       FROM test t
      )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET DisplayingOrder = newDisplayingOrder;
```

You can do both in one step:

```
WITH toupdate AS
      (SELECT t.*,
              dense_rank() over (order by ParentId) as newGroupId,
              row_number() over (partition by groupid order by idName) as newDisplayingOrder
       FROM test t
      )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET GroupId = newGroupId,
        DisplayingOrder = newDisplayingOrder;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query and update all rows with different iD Name

```
Update test set DisplayingOrder = 1 where iD Name = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

WITH CTE_View AS
      (SELECT t1.*,
              dense_rank() over (order by ParentId) as newGroupId,
              row_number() over (partition by groupid order by idName) as newDisplayingOrder
       FROM tab t1
      )
UPDATE CTE_View
    SET GroupId = newGroupId,
        DisplayingOrder = newDisplayingOrder;